# How many Handlers I need when multithreading

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler, runnable

I have tried googling for a while this but couldn't found any clear answer. I have an Android software which should listen multiple UDP ports. If I'm not mistaken, I have to create own thread for each port. After port receives data, it should be passed to the UI-thread.

After some research I concluded that I should use Handlers to provide data to the UI-thread. However, I'm a bit confused about how many Handlers I'd need. Does each Thread require its own Handler or is single shared one enough?

For some background info, I'm trying to create timed threads which check received UDP-packets every 100ms and update their contents to the UI-thread's views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `Handler` on the UI thread and pass that handler reference to each thread (so you will need only 1 handler object). In this way since the handler was created on UI thread, its `handleMessage` will be executed on UI thread - but be careful that each message processed through `handleMessage` to be executed very fast.